# select to group date and time in 5-minute intervals

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, intervals

I wish count the rows of a table grouped by date and time intervals of 5 minutes:

for example, if the minutes portion of HH:MM falls between 00 mins and 04 min it will be counted as 00, eg. 08:04 will be counted as 08:00

if the minutes portion falls between 05 mins and 09 mins it will be counted as 05, eg. 08:06 will be counted as 08:05

**Table Data**

```
Date       Time
18/01/18    08:00
18/01/18    08:01
18/01/18    08:02
18/01/18    08:03
18/01/18    08:04

18/01/18    08:05
18/01/18    08:06
18/01/18    08:08

18/01/18    08:10

19/01/18    17:01
19/01/18    17:03
19/01/18    17:04
```

**Expected Output**

```
DATE         TIME  COUNT
18/01/2018   08:00   5
18/01/2018   08:05   3
18/01/2018   08:10   1
19/01/2018   17:00   3
```

**Table Creation**

create table TAB1 (tDATE DATE,tTIME VARCHAR2(5));

**Data**

```
insert into TAB1(tDATE,tTIME) values (to_date('18/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY'),'08:00');

insert into TAB1(tDATE,tTIME) values (to_date('18/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY'),'08:01');

insert into TAB1(tDATE,tTIME) values (to_date('18/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY'),'08:02');

insert into TAB1(tDATE,tTIME) values (to_date('18/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY'),'08:03');

insert into TAB1(tDATE,tTIME) values (to_date('18/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY'),'08:04');

insert into TAB1(tDATE,tTIME) values (to_date('18/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY'),'08:05');

insert into TAB1(tDATE,tTIME) values (to_date('18/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY'),'08:06');

insert into TAB1(tDATE,tTIME) values (to_date('18/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY'),'08:08');


insert into TAB1(tDATE,tTIME) values (to_date('18/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY'),'08:10');

insert into TAB1(tDATE,tTIME) values (to_date('19/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY'),'17:01');

insert into TAB1(tDATE,tTIME) values (to_date('19/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY'),'17:03');

insert into TAB1(tDATE,tTIME) values (to_date('19/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY'),'17:04');
```

Comment: Why on earth do you store time in separate `VARCHAR2` column? Oracle `DATE` data type already contains time part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. As to why there is a separate VARCHAR2 column for the time component, the tables were originally migrated from some legacy database that had a date type but without a time component the latter which was stored as a string. Here is my own idea which gives me exactly what I want:

```
select tDATE,substr(tTIME,1,3)||
         case 
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 0 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 5 then '00' 
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 5 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 10 then '05'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 10 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 15 then '10'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 15 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 20 then '15'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 20 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 25 then '20'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 25 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 30 then '25'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 30 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 35 then '30'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 35 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 40 then '35'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 40 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 45 then '40'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 45 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 50 then '45'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 50 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 55 then '50'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 55 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 60 then '55'
           else '00'
         end as tTIME
,count(*)
from TAB1
group by tDATE,substr(tTIME,1,3)||
         case 
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 0 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 5 then '00' 
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 5 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 10 then '05'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 10 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 15 then '10'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 15 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 20 then '15'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 20 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 25 then '20'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 25 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 30 then '25'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 30 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 35 then '30'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 35 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 40 then '35'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 40 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 45 then '40'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 45 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 50 then '45'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 50 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 55 then '50'
           when to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) >= 55 and to_number(regexp_substr(substr(tTIME,4,2),'^[-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$')) < 60 then '55'
           else '00'
         end
order by 3 desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I need such interval I use this generic function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MakeInterval(ts IN TIMESTAMP, roundInterval IN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND) RETURN TIMESTAMP DETERMINISTIC IS
    denom INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' HOUR THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(HOUR FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(24, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts) + TRUNC(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
    ELSIF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' MINUTE THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'hh') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE;
    ELSE
        denom := EXTRACT(SECOND FROM roundInterval);                
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'mi') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' SECOND;
    END IF;
END MakeInterval;
```

Valid intervals are: 1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30,60 SECOND, 1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30,60 MINUTE, 1,2,3,4,6,8,12 HOUR

You store time in a separate column which is a bad design. First, make a proper `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` value, for example: `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(tDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')||tTIME, 'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI')`

Then you could use it like this

```
SELECT 
   MakeInterval(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(tDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')||tTIME, 'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI'), INTERVAL '5' MINUTE), ...
```

Of course, if you don't like to use a separate function you can put all in one line:

```
TRUNC(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(tDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')||tTIME, 'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI'), 'hh') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(tDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')||tTIME, 'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI')) / 5) * INTERVAL '5' MINUTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit cumbersome in Oracle, but quite feasible with string arithmetic:

```
select date, 
       substring(time, 1, 3) || lpad(floor(cast(substring(time, -2) as number) / 12) * 12, 2, '0') as time,
       count(*)
from tab1
group by date, 
         substring(time, 1, 3) || lpad(floor(cast(substring(time, -2) as number) / 12) * 12, 2, '0')
order by date, time;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select tdate, 
       SUBSTR(ttime, 1, 2)||':'||
              LPAD(NVL(DECODE(SIGN(ROUND(SUBSTR(ttime, 4, 2), -1)-SUBSTR(ttime, 4, 2)), 
                                 1, ROUND(SUBSTR(ttime, 4, 2), -1)-5,
                                -1, ROUND(SUBSTR(ttime, 4, 2), -1)), 0),2, '0') time_,
       count(1)
  from tab1
 group by tdate, SUBSTR(ttime, 1, 2)||':'||
                 LPAD(NVL(DECODE(SIGN(ROUND(SUBSTR(ttime, 4, 2), -1)-SUBSTR(ttime, 4, 2)), 
                                     1, ROUND(SUBSTR(ttime, 4, 2), -1)-5,
                                    -1, ROUND(SUBSTR(ttime, 4, 2), -1)), 0),2, '0');
```